# How to async an eventhandler? Wait for promise javascript

Tags: javascript, event-handling, mouseevent

```js
document.querySelector('#library').addEventListener('click', function(event) {

  new Promise((resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('set time out');
    }, 2000)
  })).then(console.log)

  // if response
  console.log('stop propagation')
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  // else
}, true)
```

I need to click an element. This will make a request and based on response (will return `true` or `false`), this will enable or disabled the click. But `console.log('stop propagation')` is executed before `.then(console.log)`.

Comment: You may need to define the Callback-Function as async and use async/await. See https://gist.github.com/nickytonline/069fc006d1946279a31fed10a61d08c5

Comment: You cannot really disable click until a promise resolves. What you can do is disable the click and then after the promise resolves do an action (or not do an action) based on the promise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't wait for an asynchronous operation to complete if you want to stop propagation and prevent the default. In this case your promise wont halt the code at all, [but even if you implement a "sleep" function properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914235) (using `async`/`await`), it will still need to wait for the promise to resolve, before it is able to know whether it should continue or not. JavaScript doesn't wait for that answer and will execute the default action and propagate further before you decide to stop that.

If you want to postpone this action, you'll have to *first* prevent the default and the propagation, then wait for the promise to resolve and then if the answer is to your satisfaction, continue with whatever it should be doing.

```js
document.querySelector('#library').addEventListener('click', async function(event) {
  console.log('stop propagation')
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();

  const returnValue = await new Promise((resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('set time out');
    }, 2000)
  })).then(resolvedValue => {
    console.log(resolvedValue);
    return resolvedValue;
  })

  if (returnValue === 'set time out') {
    location.href = event.target.href;
  }
}, true)
```

```html
<a id="library" href="http://www.google.com/">Click</a>
```